# How to convert timestamp (with dot between second and millisecond) to date(yyyyMMdd) in Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, time, hive, hiveql

I want to convert timestamp, `1490198341.705` for example, to date `20170323` and to hour `11` (GMT+8:00). Are there any functions to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select date_format(from_utc_timestamp(1490198341.705,'GMT+8:00'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss');
```