# converting from string to timestamp including milliseconds in hive

Tags: hive

I'm trying to convert from string to timestamp in hive I'm using mentioned below code

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("12/20/2012 00:54:26.001000", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") as CURR_TS
```

I'm getting output as `12/20/2012 00:54:27`(seconds getting round off)
but I want output as  `12/20/2012 00:54:26.001000`

Comment: iam facing this error while changed to ffffffError while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: unix_timestamp  does not support ms apparently. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701847/hives-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime-functions

Comment: bad time and date status

Comment: my requirement to get exactly same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive's unix\_timestamp and from\_unixtime functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701847/hives-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime-functions)

Comment: Have a look also at this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975950/2700344